# SQL assign ID partition by

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, partitioning

I want to assign unique IDs to **groups** of rows which meet some criteria. In the following sample, I want to assign an unique ID based on **data and hardware**

Example:

```
date, hardware, color
1990, 8989, blue
1990, 8989, yellow
1991, 8989, blue
1991, 3333, blue
1991, 8989, black
```

Expected result

```
date, hardware, color, ID
1990, 8989, blue, 1
1990, 8989, yellow, 1
1991, 8989, blue, 2
1991, 3333, blue, 3
1991, 8989, black, 2
```

How can I achieve this result in BigQuery?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use [`DENSE_RANK`](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/analytic-function-concepts):

```
select t.*,dense_rank() over (order by date, hardware) as id
from table_name t;
```

**[db<>fiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=aef04922f42b61530dc83e0732ea5287)**

Comment: Your solution is much better than mine. So concise. +1

Comment: Thank you, it's what I was looking for

Answer (score 2):

I would do:

```
with
x as (
  select distinct date, hardware from my_table
),
y as (
  select 
    date, 
    hardware, 
    row_number() over(order by date, hardware) as rn
  from x
)
select
  t.*, y.rn
from my_table t
join y on y.date = t.date and y.hardware = t.hardware
```

Comment: Yours solution also works [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=02adc96e8adc09e71f28c22a49de535e). Please remove `,` before last select

Comment: Fixed. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Window functions in BigQuery can have problems on large data when there is no `partition by` clause.  They can run out of resources.

Another alternative is to assign an id using hashing:

```
select t.*, farm_fingerprint(cast(date as string), '|', hardware) as id
from table_name t;
```

The `id`s are not as elegant.  However, elegant ids are of little consolation if your query fails due to a lack of resources.